# Swift - image hiding

Tags: ios, swift, image

I have a problem. I'm using swift 2.0 this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
```

I'm using label and image for contents in cell. When the contents have no image, I see empty space in cells.

[image]

If the contents have no image, how can I hide the image and remove the empty space.

I tried to use this code but not work:

```
cell.contentImage.hidden = true
```

and I'm using:

```
 let thumb = UIImage(named: "dreamImage")
        cell.dreamImage.image = thumb
            if let thumbnailx = object?["image"] as? PFFile {
                cell.dreamImage.file = thumbnailx
                cell.dreamImage.loadInBackground()
        }
```

Also I'm using parse and `PFImageView`. I tried:

```
if thumbnailx == nil {
   cell.dreamImage.hidden = true
}else {
   cell.dreamImage.hidden = false 
}
```

but I received a warning **"Pffile can never be nil"**

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: Please do not change the meaning of your question after solving it. You can always create a new post with a follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a condition for thumbnailx being `nil`:

```
if let thumbnailx = object?["image"] as? PFFile {
    cell.dreamImage.file = thumbnailx
    cell.dreamImage.loadInBackground()
    cell.dreamImage.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.dreamImage.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: This is not work for me. My main problem that there is empty space in cells so i try your code but i saw empty space again. 

I want to see my timeline like twitter timeline. When tweets have no image, there is no empty space under the label.


Thank you

Comment: This is an unrelated problem for which you should create a new post.